# Spring insert using jdbc

Tags: java, spring, sql-insert, jdbctemplate, sqlyog

I have a table in SQLYog where one column is varchar limit to 200 length.
I wrote the method below for the insert, but when testing the code the column "Name" is not been filled by the data in the DB.

```
@Override
public void insert(final List<InfoRow> rows) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO info_table (ID, NAME, AGE) VALUES (?, SUBSTRING(?, 0, 200), ?)";

    jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i)
                throws SQLException {
            InfoRow row= rows.get(i);
            ps.setInt(1, (int) row.getId());
            ps.setString(2, row.getName());
            ps.setInt(3,(int) row.getAge());
        }

        @Override
        public int getBatchSize() {
            return rows.size();
        }
    });

}
```

What is the correct way to validate the 'Name' size while insert?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substring expressions in MySQL (this is a guess based on the sqlyog tag) are 1 based, not 0 based. Try this instead:

```
SUBSTRING(?, 1, 200)
```

Generally, I would keep validation logic out of the database layer, and handle "bad input" in the application layer. This allows me to log the fact that data would be dropped/truncated.

But this approach is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to validate inputs is in your service layer not your model layer like you are describing here. The DAO should be responsible just for persist data not to validate.

You should have a service calling the `insert(List<InfoRow>);` method and there have to be your validation.